# Understand Laravel 5.3 Events

Tags: laravel

I create event using command php artisan event:make EventTest and that generates this class:

```
class EventTest
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Official documentation for Laravel 5.3 Events however looks different https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#defining-events, event that it uses as example looks like this:

```
class OrderShipped extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param  Order  $order
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

As you can see it extends Event, my Event created by artisan does not extend Event, also my class uses InteractsWithSockets while class on laravel documentation does not. Why this difference, what does it mean? Is Laravel's 5.3 documentation already out of date and not updated to reflect latest changes?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're correct. It looks like this particular part of the documentation was not updated with the 5.3 release.

To answer your question more completely, Laravel 5.3 no longer uses the [abstract Event class](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Events/Event.php) you were seeing referenced in the 5.2 documentation.

The abstraction itself was unnecessary, and so it was removed.

As for the `InteractsWithSockets` trait you're seeing, that was added for a more seamless integration with Websockets. If your application isn't using Websockets (see: [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)), then you don't have to leverage these traits and the use statement may be removed safely.

Anyone may edit the documentation, so you may want to consider putting in a pull request with the docs [here](https://github.com/laravel/docs).